# Does my Disparity Map look right?

Tags: image, opencv, point-clouds, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

[Disparity map of two rectified images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEu28.jpg)

[Point cloud of the disparity map (side view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tguJt.jpg)

Looking to the point cloud from the front it seems to be good, but as you can see the point cloud is consisting from many slices...
It seems that something is wrong with the Z-coordinate?

There are ~24 of these slices and the disparity map pixel values have the range[0,23]..
So maybe my disparity map is wrong?

Comment: we don't know what device you're working with, but those slices look alright.the distance between them looks logarithmic so i suppose it must just be a visitation thing in rviz?

Comment: but you think my disparity map looks right?  
because for example the surface of the car is black on the disparity map (like the background in the image), 
but i think the objects more near to the camera should result to more bright/white pixels in the disparity map?